# Melisandre's Green Eye Prophecy for Arya

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In s08e03 we see Melisandre and Arya meet for the second time after Season 3 when Melisandre said to Arya back then:

> "I see a darkness in you. And in that darkness, eyes staring back at me. Brown eyes, blue eyes, green eyes. Eyes you'll shut forever. We will meet again. "

I think **Blue Eyes** referred to the Night King and the White Walkers since we saw Arya killing the Night King in s08e03.

I also believe that **Brown Eyes** referred to Walder Frey who was also killed by Arya back in Season 6.

But where do the **Green Eyes** reffer to? I don't remember her executing any important character with green eyes. My guess is that:

> they reffer to Cersei. Do you think that  the prophecy implies that she is going to bring her hateful enemy down somehow?

Comment: Same question on SFF: [Who has green eyes and was/were killed by Arya?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211093/98028)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible that any of the dozens of dead Freys could have green eyes.

Comment: @Jenayah Didn't notice.Should I delete the question?

Comment: Nah, as long as it's not an intentional cross-posting (which doesn't seem to be), you're fine. (I mean if you want to delete it, you can as well, it's your call) I'm mostly dropping those "asked and answered on SFF" links for curious readers/additional info, as sister sites are a bit intertwined :)

Comment: Brown eyes could also have been Meryn Trant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Unclear.

Some of the possibilities are Littlefinger, Cersei, and Jaime.

> The obvious answer is Cersei Lannister, as Arya has been out to get her since Season 1 for her role in Ned Stark's imprisonment (which ultimately led to his death) and more tragedies on her house. The Queen of the Seven Kingdoms has green eyes, both in the A Song of Ice and Fire books and the show Game of Thrones.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Who Has Green Eyes on Game of Thrones? - HarperBazaar](https://www.harpersbazaar.com/culture/film-tv/a27303477/who-has-green-eyes-on-game-of-thrones/)</sub>

This does seem likely but there are the other possibilities, like Petyr.

> The prophecy may also refer to Littlefinger (a.k.a. Petyr Baelish),
>   whom Arya already killed in Season 7. He's said to have gray-green
>   eyes in the books. (In real life, however, actor Aiden Gillen has blue
>   eyes.) Maybe Arya has already fulfilled her prophecy and sealed the
>   deal with the Night King as her victim.
>
> Plus, consider the order of eye colors Melisandre says to Arya. In
>   Season 3, the order was brown, blue green, but in last night's
>   episode, the order was brown, green, blue. Perhaps the brown and
>   green-eyed kills had already happened and the blue-eyed takedown was
>   the final piece of the puzzle.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Who Has Green Eyes on Game of Thrones? - HarperBazaar](https://www.harpersbazaar.com/culture/film-tv/a27303477/who-has-green-eyes-on-game-of-thrones/)</sub>

The final considerable option is that it may refer to Jaime *and* Cersei.

> As Cersei's twin brother, Jaime also has the green Lannister eyes, at least in the ASOIF books. Some fans theorize that Arya will kill the Kingslayer and then use his face to kill his sister. That idea also aligns with the valonqar theory Cersei received as a child, which says she'll die at the hands of her little brother.
>
> ### [image: Alt theory. Arya doesn't kill Cersi but kills Jaime (green eyes) then takes his face to help kill Circe]
>
> <sub>[Who Has Green Eyes on Game of Thrones? - HarperBazaar](https://www.harpersbazaar.com/culture/film-tv/a27303477/who-has-green-eyes-on-game-of-thrones/)</sub>

Hopefully, we will receive some confirmation later in the series.

Comment: Update: we didn’t.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Unfortunately no

Comment: Is it mentioned what colour the Waif's eyes were?